# JavaScript setInterval() not showing contents?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

My javascript code isn't working.  I went to the page and it was displaying the content.  Why isn't it appending the data to .userStats? invest_process.php contains the information that grabs the values shown in the PHP.  That's not what would be causing the issue. Thanks, code below.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="content1" class="tabscontent">
<p>
<span class="userStats"></span>
</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh_stats = setInterval(
function (){
    $('.userStats').load('get_user_stats.php').show();
}, 1000 );
</script>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
require 'invest_process.php';

echo 
'<span><h3>You have: 
' . $select_invested['amtInvested'] . 
' Invested in GigaDice | You have: 
' . $select_invested['amtInvested']/$select_invested_total['siteInvested']*100 . 
' % of the site\'s bankroll</span></h3> <span><h3> You have 
' . $select_balance_gg['gigagold'] . 
' in GG Balance | You have profitted: 
' . $siteProfit*$select_invested['amtInvested']/$select_invested_total['siteInvested'] . 
'</span></h3>';
?>
```

Comment: Right now it is suppose to overwrite. if you want to append then use `append()`

Comment: Did you put the Javascript part after the HTML? Otherwise you need to use `$(document).ready()` or equivalent

Comment: I want it to overwrite.  Didn't mean to say append.

Comment: It's working intermittenly right now.

Comment: intermittently? meaning instead of refreshing every second, it refreshes at odd intervals?

Comment: Are you certain the data changes? Is it just reloading with the same data? Also make sure your browser isn't caching the result which can be done by setting ajaxSetup. `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});` before you run the .load

Answer (score 1):

Add `$(document).ready()` block

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var auto_refresh_stats = setInterval(
   function ()
   {
     $('.userStats').load('get_user_stats.php').show();  // if you want to replace
   }, 1000 );
});
```

If you want to append the contents then use the following

```
 $('.userStats').append($('<div>').load('get_user_stats.php'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh_stats = setInterval(
function (){
  $('.userStats').load('get_user_stats.php');
}, 1000 );
</script>
```